# Проблемы с pip на Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Изначально при попытке установки модуля через pip возникала ошибка при этом pip просил обновится, т.к. у меня стояла еще 8 версия. Обновил, после этого при попытке установить модуль возникает ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После этого почитав на форумах ответы решил pip просто переустановить, но после попытки удаления:

```
sudo apt purge python-pip
```

возникает ошибка со словами будто pip не установлен:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но тут же при проверки версии pip - версию пишет:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно восстановить нормальную работу pip?

Comment: ``install /home/oleg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip /usr/bin/`` от рута

Comment: tkinter — модуль, встроенный в любом питоне, его совершенно не нужно устанавливать

Comment: А несистемный pip наверно можно попробовать удалить командой типа `pip uninstall pip` (без sudo, он же у вас не системный)

Comment: У меня было что-то подобное не сервере. Я не уверен, но не может ли это быть связано с версией python. Типа pip - это от второго питона. А от третьего питона pip3.

Comment: Ошибку с установкой  решил, возможно точно была проблема с версиями: sudo apt-get install python3.5 python3.5-tk, но невозможность удаления pip все же настораживает, как можно вообще всю среду python переустановить?